# Azure AD B2C - how we manage application wise users data ? (single/same tenant)

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I have azure b2c single tenant and it has multiple applications with one website SSO. 
We configured b2c application 'A' with website 'A'. we need another set of users who also connect with website 'A' with SSO login so we created another b2c application 'B' inside same tanent. 
Both b2c applications signup fields are different as per requirement.

Problem : user 'X' has signup and sign in with b2c application 'A' and website 'A'.
same user 'X' will do sign up in b2c application 'B' and it gives error that "Already registered"

So how I manage application wise users set of records ? And how we manage sign up different data with same user ?

Answer (score 1):

If your apps absolutely require the user to have signed up with a certain set of attributes, then the application will need to check the incoming users id_token, or do a Graph API call to determine if their profile is incomplete.

In this case it should send them to a Profile Edit screen (B2C policy) to update their profile before the application allows the user to continue using the service.

Each App should then have its own Profile Edit policy to manage the attributes that are relevant to it.